# Why does this GROUP BY and NA combo produce a character type?

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Why does `y` end up as a `character` class?  Seems like that should never happen from a `sqldf` SUM?

```
library(sqldf)

# three very similar data.frame objects
x <- structure(list(size = c(1L, 2L), diff = c(1, NA)) , .Names = c("gb","diff"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
y <- structure(list(size = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), diff = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)) , .Names = c("gb","diff"), row.names = 1:4, class = "data.frame")
z <- structure(list(size = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), diff = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)) , .Names = c("gb","diff"), row.names = 1:4, class = "data.frame")


# when summed in sqldf: numeric, character, numeric
sapply(sqldf("select sum(diff) from x"),class)
sapply(sqldf("select sum(diff) , gb from y group by gb"),class)[1]
sapply(sqldf("select sum(diff) , gb from z group by gb"),class)[1]



# this despite both being numeric originally
class( x$diff )
class( y$diff )
```

Comment: If I remove that `sum()` and leave only `diff` results is as expected (both numeric). I do not know sql and so sum. In R `sum` is a generic function for sum up elements. Maybe R commands inside `sqldf` functions need to be put in a special function or something?

Comment: I think this applies: sqldf FAQ 14: https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#14-how-does-one-read-files-where-numeric-nas-are-represented-as-missing-empty-fields

Comment: @BondedDust thanks!  that's probably part of the problem.  i've submitted a slightly-clarified issue, but i should just write a work-around :)  https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/2

Answer (score 3):

Exclude `NA`, (i.e.: `NULL`) before aggregating:

```
out1 <- sqldf("SELECT SUM(diff) AS diff_sum
               FROM x
               WHERE diff IS NOT NULL")

out2 <- sqldf("SELECT SUM(diff) AS diff_sum, gb
               FROM y
               WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
               GROUP BY gb")

str(out1)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ diff_sum: num 1
str(out2)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ diff_sum: num 1
# $ gb      : int 2
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is the correct way to avoid this.](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf/issues/2)

@G.Grothendieck :

> sqldf has a heuristic that will
>   set the class on any output column to be the same class as an input
>   column of the same name so this would fix it:

```
str(y)
## 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ gb  : int  1 1 2 2
##  $ diff: num  NA NA 1 NA

out1 <- sqldf("select sum(diff) diff, gb from y group by gb")
str(out1)
## 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ diff: num  NA 1
##  $ gb  : int  1 2

out2 <- sqldf("select sum(diff) diff, gb from y group by gb ORDER BY gb desc")
str(out2)
## 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
## $ diff: num  1 NA
## $ gb  : int  2 1
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck does this mean we cannot rename the output variable, for example to `diff_sum` and have it as numeric?